# Hecke operators - why is it well-defined?

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms

I have a basic question concerning Hecke Operators in spaces of Modular Forms. I am followinf these notes: http://www.few.vu.nl/~sdn249/modularforms16/Notes.pdf. In page 49, the author writes

> **Proposition 4.1.** Let $\Gamma$ be a congruence subgroup, let $k$ be an integer and let $\alpha\in\mathrm{GL}_2^+(\mathbb{Q})$. Then for any $f\in M_k(\Gamma)$, the function $T_\alpha f$ is again in $M_k(\Gamma)$.

He then leaves the proof of this Proposition as an exercise. I am failing to solve this exercise. Essentially, we want to show that $(T_\alpha f)|_k\eta=T_\alpha f$ for any $\eta\in\Gamma$. Now, from the Definition of $T_\alpha f$, we can write
$$(T_\alpha f)|_k\eta=\sum_{\gamma\in\Gamma'\setminus\Gamma}f|_k \alpha\gamma\eta$$
and one natural way to show that this equals $T_\alpha f$ would be to show that, if $(\gamma_i)_{i\in I}$ is a complete set of representatives of right cosets of $\Gamma$ modulo $\Gamma'$, then so is $(\gamma_i\eta)_{i\in I}$. But I see no reason why this should be true. Can someone help?

Comment: Isn’t this obvious because multiplication by $\eta$ acts on the set of cosets by some map, and $\eta^{-1}$ gives the inverse map?

Comment: I recommend that you consult Shimura: Introduction to the arithmetic theory of automorphic functions.

Answer (score 3):

Write the double coset $\Gamma \alpha \Gamma$ as the finite disjoint union of simple cosets $\Gamma \alpha_1,\ldots,\Gamma \alpha_n$. Then mulplication on the right by $\eta$ is well-defined on $\Gamma \alpha \Gamma$, and it permutes the cosets $\Gamma \alpha_i$.